# Modify this code to remove the "year" part

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this code and I have to remove the year part of it, it's a formatter for date values in a form, it has to be "DD/MM" but it is "MM/DD/YYYY" can someone help me?

```
<input type="text" name="datada" id="dtDataDa" placeholder="" value="%dtDataDa%"/>
```

**THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE TO MODIFY**

```
var date = document.getElementById('dtDataDa');

function checkValue(str, max) {
    if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
        var num = parseInt(str);
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
        str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
    };
    return str;
};

date.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    this.type = 'text';
    var input = this.value;
    if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
    var values = input.split('/').map(function (v) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
    });
    if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
    if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
    var output = values.map(function (v, i) {
        return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
    });
    this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
});

date.addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
    this.type = 'text';
    var input = this.value;
    var values = input.split('/').map(function (v, i) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
    });
    var output = '';

    if (values.length == 3) {
        var year = values[2].length !== 4 ? parseInt(values[2]) + 2000 : parseInt(values[2]);
        var month = parseInt(values[0]) - 1;
        var day = parseInt(values[1]);
        var d = new Date(year, month, day);
        if (!isNaN(d)) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = d.toString();
            var dates = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()];
            output = dates.map(function (v) {
                v = v.toString();
                return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
            }).join(' / ');
        };
    };
    this.value = output;
});
```

It makes the form insert only real digits, for the month (1s part) numbers until 12, for the days (2nd part) numbers until 31 and for the year (3rd part) there is no rule.. I would like to have only the month and days part of it so that an example would look like "06/18"

Here you can see it https://codepen.io/user23xx/pen/VdarOL?editors=1010

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to show what you tried at least so others can help

Comment: My attempts where meaningless, I didn't make the code and also I'm a beginner with this..

Comment: codepen is not working...when click on input nothing happen

Comment: mine works, try to create a new pen pasting the code above, if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite simple to modify from the code you've shared. 
Look for the comments at `addEventListener`

```
date.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    this.type = 'text';
    var input = this.value;
    if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
    var values = input.split('/').map(function (v) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
    });
    if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 31); //Put 31 instead of 12
    if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 12); //Put 12 instead of 31
    var output = values.map(function (v, i) {
        return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
    });
    this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 7); //Update to 7 instead of 14 because full length you want is 7
});
```

Next we want to update the blur method as below

```
if (!isNaN(d)) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerText = d.toString();
            var dates = [d.getDate(),d.getMonth() + 1];//Remove the year part
            output = dates.map(function (v) {
                v = v.toString();
                return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
            }).join(' / ');
        };
```

**UPDATES**:

```
date.addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
    this.type = 'text';
    var input = this.value;
    var values = input.split('/').map(function (v, i) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
    });
    var output = '';

    if (values.length == 2) {

      var dates = [values[0], values[1]];
      output = dates.map(function (v) {
        v = v.toString();
        return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
      }).join(' / ');
    };

    this.value = output;
});
```

Comment: Wow thank you!! You completely solved my problem.. But now there is a new issue: the value you write disappear when you click outside of the form and doesn't  ""save"" it inside of it, it just cancells once you've done with it

Comment: It should be working fine as I've tested with your codepen. Trying to access your codepen seems gone?

Comment: I was updating it with the changes you gave me, here it is https://codepen.io/user23xx/pen/oyxEMy

Comment: @user23xx: Have a look at the updates, however, since you ignore the year, so this is no longer a valid date and remain a pure string

Comment: Hy @Isaac I was looking a bit into this and was wondering if you could provide me an answer on this. would it be bad to just insert a maxlength = "7" in the input field and then just change 'return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;' to 'return v.length == 2 && i < 1 ? v + ' / ' : v;'. Cause this also seems to work but I'm new to javascript and don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: @Isaac you're amazing!! thank you so much!
Have a lovely day.

Comment: @user23xx: Do mark it as answer if it solved your problem. thanks

Comment: @mrdeadsven: `i` will not be able to be 2 and so yes your solution works too